# Remove but NOT delete a `has_and_belongs_to_many through` model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do you handle a Model that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for another Model, where  you only want `first_or_initialize` that child model? At the same time, be able delete the relationship between the two?

For instance if you have a `Job` model that has many `Tags`.

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :Tags
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :Tags, allow_destroy: true
    validates :tags, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 2 }
    ....
```

and a Tags can have many Jobs

```
class Tags < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
```

When a user fills out a Job form, they can enter in a couple tags for the job.
Using `fields_for` on the form handles this.

If there is already a tag in the database with name `Python` then a new tag shouldn't be created called `Python`. On the other hand, if this is the first time `Python` was used the database should create a new `Tag` with name `Python`.

At the same time if the user decides to remove `Python` tag, and updates the job — the `Python` tag is not deleted, only its associated record is deleted. Other Job using the same using the  `Python` tag are unaffected. Similarly, if the user retypes the text  `Python` to say `Postgres`, it doesn't update the `Python` tag, it creates a new one. So again, other Jobs using the same using the  `Python` tag are unaffected.

How is something like this done?

I took at stab at it, but I've so far only got the uniqueness side of this working. (The deleting of associated record isn't working).

In the Job Model this callback for `before_validation` will prevent saving / updating dupes.

```
before_validation :find_tag

  private

  def find_tag
    repos = self.tags.map do |tag|
      Tag.where(name: tag.name).first_or_initialize
    end
    self.tags = tags
  end
```

But when deleting a `Tag`, it breaks, I think because of the 
`validates :tags, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 2 }`

I.E. A two tags are deleted in the UI, another three are sent — five are present in the params (two with `_destroy`, three new ones). The `before_validation` callback runs first and causes the update to fail.

Hopefully I made sense describing this issue. Any pointers on this type of thing?

---

EDIT

also trying to override attr setters..

```
 def tags_attributes=(attributes)
    attributes.values.map do |repo|
      Tag.where(url: repo[:url]).first_or_initialize
    end
  end
```

But still unable to delete

Comment: Can you please share the controller code where you accept params from form, the actual params value you're getting from the form there, and also the migrations for creating tags and jobs tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood correctly the situation this would be the answer:

So this part:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, through: :tags_assignments
```

commonly means that there is a database table that preserves Post <-> Tag relations.
So if you want to remove a tag from a post you would have to delete that link (or entry from that table). Given that you're working with Rails if everything is set up properly you would have a file `YOUR_APP/models/tags_assignment.rb` that defines TagsAssignment model, e.g.:

```
class TagsAssignment < ApplicationRecord
...
end
```

and then you could just do:

```
TagsAssignment.where(
  post_id: id_of_my_post,
  tag_id: id_of_my_tag
).destroy_all
```

**EDIT**: The above is kind of what happens behind the scene but you could perhaps use this to achieve the same:

```
...
tag = Tag.find(tag_id)
Post.find(id).tags.delete(tag) # or use destroy if you want callbacks
...
```

Comment: Would this require me change it to a `has_many`?
I was under the imporession `has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't have associated model.

Comment: The `through:` part is the key. Based on the name we can assume the relation is formed via 'link' table

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding. In order to manage the relationship via `TagsAssignment` model, isn't it necessary to change it from a `has_and_belongs_to_many though` to a `has_many though`. In Rails guides it says that `has_and_belongs_to_many` is managed through a join table not a join model, whereas a `has_many though` has a join model..

Comment: Also, if I send a `_destroy` param in `tag_attributes` to the Post Controller, the `Post#Update` method would need to know how to remove the `Tag` association instead of deleting it, right?

Comment: So I guess the question should be, if anyone knows the answer. How do you delete an association, NOT associated model when using a the has_and_belongs_to_many though..

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't have a `through` option, it does however have a `join_table` one

Comment: I've updated my original question, hopefully I've illustrated the issue better now.